# Wait until service starts in bash-script

Tags: linux, bash

I've a bash-script that starts some service in background. After this service successfully starts it prints "Server is active" to the stdout. I need to wait until this string appears and then continue executing my script. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't do that. Make your script a service itself. Then it may depend if you use `systemd` or plain old SysV init....

Comment: Or even just make a lock file when it starts, or check pid, or something else, no reason to capture `stdout` here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would do in this way.

```
./server > /tmp/server-log.txt &
sleep 1
while ! grep -m1 'Server is active' < /tmp/server-log.txt; do
    sleep 1
done

echo Continue
```

Here `-m1` tells `grep(1)` to quit at the first match.

I veryfied my answer with my toy "service" below:

```
#! /bin/bash

trap "echo 'YOU killed me with SIGPIPE!' 1>&2 " SIGPIPE

rm -f /tmp/server-output.txt
for (( i=0; i<5; ++i )); do
    echo "i==$i"
    sleep 1;
done
echo "Server is active"
for (( ; i<10; ++i )); do
    echo "i==$i"
    sleep 1;
done
echo "Server is shutting down..." > /tmp/server-output.txt
```

If you replace `echo Continue` with `echo Continue; sleep 1; ls /tmp/server-msg.txt`, you will see `ls: cannot access /tmp/server-output.txt: No such file or directory` which proves the "Continue" action was triggered right after the output of `Server is active`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `grep -q`. The `-q` option makes `grep` quiet, and it will exit immediately when the text appears.

The command below starts `./some-service` in the background, and blocks until "Server is active" appears on stdout.

```sh
(./some-service &) | grep -q "Server is active"
```

Comment: This is awesome! I did something like this:

`/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr > /root/sqlservr.out &` and then 
`tail -f /root/sqlservr.out | grep -q "SQL Server is now ready"`

Answer (score 5):

For me to read service's status as to `service` app:

```
$ /sbin/service network status
network.service - Network Connectivity
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/network.service; enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Ср 2014-01-29 22:00:06 MSK; 1 day 15h ago
  Process: 15491 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

$ /sbin/service httpd status 
httpd.service - SYSV: Apache is a World Wide Web server.  It is used to serve HTML files and CGI.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd)
   Active: activating (start) since Пт 2014-01-31 13:59:06 MSK; 930ms ago
```

and it can be done with the code:

```
function is_in_activation {
   activation=$(/sbin/service "$1" status | grep "Active: activation" )
   if [ -z "$activation" ]; then
      true;
   else
      false;
   fi

   return $?;
}

while is_in_activation network ; do true; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking redirect stderr to stdout?

```
./yourscript.sh  2>&1 |grep "Server is active" && echo "continue executing my script"
```